# installation issue in kbmMWRunDXE7ENT

Tags: delphi

I cannot compile `kbmMWRunDXE7ENT.dproj`

I have Delphi XE7 Ent update 1 and kbmMemTable 7.7.2 installed.
Indy version is 10.6.1.5182.

The compiler error is

> kbmMWUdpIndyMessagingClientTransport.pas(216): E2009 Incompatible
>   types: 'Parameter lists differ' on a line in Constructor
>   FSocket.OnUDPRead := OnUDPRead

Comment: Why don't you ask the [component vendor](http://www.components4programmers.com/)? I presume they will deliver support for this problem.

Comment: I am using StackOverflow according to their Free Support model

Comment: You are using the enterprise component, not the freeware component. Are you sure you did buy this?

Comment: of course, I did buy Enterprise product but I did not buy Paid Support. Probably my emails sent to its support are refused by its spam filters. So I have no idea how to get its supprt

Comment: I comment out Indy UDP in config.

Comment: It is solved according to kind advise of the developer

Comment: Then you should upvote and accept his answer. Glad to hear you sorted it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written on our support page at www.components4developers.com, you can access our public newsgroups at news://news.components4developers.com and post questions there.

Mail sent directly to us will be replied to as soon as we can, but it's correct that we will prioritize 'Paid Support'. Currently we are just very busy... actually we always are.

You mention RemoteThinClient. It's a very different beast from kbmMW Enterprise Edition. With kbmMW Enterprise Edition you have the most complete n-tier framework in existence for Delphi/C++Builder with far more features and options than found in any of the competing products. So, after you get used to the way kbmMW works, I hope that you will find it to not be a regrettable purchase.

With regards to your questions then, I suspect that your Delphi XE7 installation found an Indy version other than the default one delivered with Delphi, or the setting in kbmMWConfig.inc is incorrect.

Make sure that you have this line uncommented:

{$DEFINE KBMMW_SUPPORT_INDY_10_6_0}

and all other KBMMW_SUPPORT_INDY lines commented.

Since kbmMW supports so many different 3rd-party frameworks, and versions of those (like numerous Indy versions), it needs you to tell it what to use and which version of it to support. That is done in kbmMWConfig.inc.

It's important not to select everything when installing kbmMW at first, because then you enable support for stuff for which you most likely will not have installed the 3rd-party requirements, and then kbmMW can't compile.

It's easy to solve it however, just open kbmMWConfig.inc, and comment out everything that you are not 100% certain you have installed beforehand, and configured a library path to in the Delphi Tools/Options/Paths dialog.

Im copying this reply to your email too.

Best Regards,
Kim/C4D

Comment: Dear Kim Madsen,
Thank you for your answer.
I have written to StackOverflow about my regret not to think twice before.
I am sorry. Now I fix the reply.
Yes, your product is quite different from RTC and the best solution for n-tier applications.
According to the documentation I have commented UDP Indy in kbmMWConfig.inc
and KBMMW are successfully installed.
I will try to do what you say and recompile and reinstall kbmMW.
However I\d like to say that I have not updated Indy from the original Delphi XE7.1.
Maybe it was caused by UniGUI installer.